# translating code from glmer to gam (general additive model)

Tags: r

I was using the glmer code for a logistic regression model with 2.5 million observations. However, after I added the multi-level component (a few hundred thousand groups), the data was too large to run in a timely manner on my computer. I want to try a [general additive model](https://m-clark.github.io/posts/2019-10-20-big-mixed-models/) instead, but I am confused about how to write the code.

The glmer code is as follows:

```
mylogit.m1a <- glmer(outcome ~ 
                    exposure*risk+ tenure.yr + CurrentAge + percap.inc.k + employment + rentership + pop.change + pop.den.k + 
                    (1 | geo_id / house_id),
                    data = temp, family = "binomial", control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", calc.derivs=FALSE))
print(Sys.time()-start)
```

The example I found writes the gam like this:

```
ga_model = gam(
  Reaction ~  Days + s(Subject, bs = 're') + s(Days, Subject, bs = 're'),
  data = sleepstudy,
  method = 'REML'
)
```

But I am confused about why there are two bits in parenthesis / what I should put in parenthesis to specify the model correctly.

Comment: don't have time to answer right now, but see `?mgcv::smooth.construct.re.smooth.spec`: when there are two bits in the parenthesis that corresponds to an interaction between them, which is equivalent to nesting (in this case) Days within Subject. (I have a bit more to say but can't right now.)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I still think I'm a bit out of my depth. I'm not sure how I'd treat an interaction term in that case, or really expand it out with so many more variables. But maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The details are given in `?smooth.construct.re.smooth.spec`:

> Exactly how the random effects are implemented is best seen by
> example. Consider the model term ‘s(x,z,bs="re")’. This will
> result in the model matrix component corresponding to ‘~x:z-1’
> being added to the model matrix for the whole model.

So `s(Days, Subject, bs = "re")` is equivalent to the `(0 + Days|Subject)` term in the `lmer` model: both of them encode "random variation in slope with respect to day across subjects"

So your `(1 | geo_id / house_id)` would be translated to `mgcv` syntax as

```
s(geo_id, bs = "re") + s(geo_id, house_id, bs = "re")
```

(the nesting syntax `a/b` expands in general to `a + a:b`).

A couple of other comments:

- you should probably use `bam()` as a drop-in replacement for `gam()` (much faster)
- you may very well run into problems with memory usage: `mgcv` doesn't use sparse matrices for the random effects terms, so they can get **big**